# Closed form for $\min_x \sum_k \|(a_k^Tx) / \|x\|^2 x -a_k \|^2$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given vectors $\boldsymbol{a}_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$, and vector $\boldsymbol{x}$, all in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Does there exist a closed form solution for the following problem?
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{x}^* = \arg\min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \sum_k \| \frac{\boldsymbol{a}_k^T \boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|^2} \boldsymbol{x} -\boldsymbol{a}_k \|^2 \,.
\end{equation}

The trivial case is when $n=1$, in which case obviously $\boldsymbol{x}^*=c\, \boldsymbol{a}_1$, where $c$ is any non-zero scalar. However, I am curious if closed form exists also for when $n>1$.

Thanks

Golabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix with the $a_k$ as rows. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_k\left\| \frac{\boldsymbol{a}_k^T \boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|^2} \boldsymbol{x} -\boldsymbol{a}_k \right\|^2
&= \sum_k\left(\frac{|a_k^Tx|^2}{\|x\|^4}\|x\|^2 - 2\frac{a_k^Tx}{\|x\|^2}x^Ta_k + \|a_k\|^2 \right)\\
&= \sum_k\|a_k\|^2 - \sum_k\frac{|a_k^Tx|^2}{\|x\|^2}\\
&= Tr(A^TA) - \sum_k\left|a_k^T\frac x{\|x\|}\right|^2\\
&= Tr(A^TA) - \left\|A\frac x{\|x\|}\right\|^2.
\end{align*}
Hence, your function of $x$ is independent of the norm of $x$. Thus, it suffices to minimize over $\{x : \|x\|=1\}$ and the minimum equals $Tr(A^TA) - \|A\|^2$, where $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$. The minimum is thus equal to $Tr(A^TA)-\|A^TA\|$ and $\|A^TA\|$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$. The maximum of $\|Ax\|^2$ is therefore attained at each normalized eigenvector $x$ of $A^TA$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.